# Double curly brackets in HTML angular file not showing the data through javascript, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a project using Angular and trying to get data through an angularjs controller to html file by using double curly brackets in my html as `{{vm.loggedInUser}}`, although my code isn't showing any error when compiled and everything is working fine, why is the data(i.e `vm.loggedInUser=decodedToken.Username`) through the controller not showing up inside my html file after calling?

This is the angular controller code:

```
angular.module('users').controller('loginController',loginController);

function 
loginController ($http,$location,$window,authfactory,jwtHelper) 
{    
    var vm=this;
    vm.isLoggedin=function(){

        if (authfactory.isLoggedin){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };

    vm.login=function(){   
        if(vm.Username && vm.Password){
            var user={
                Username:vm.Username,
                Password:vm.Password
            };

            $http.post('/api/login',user).then(function(response){
                if(response.data.success){
                    $window.sessionStorage.token=response.data.token;
                    var token=$window.sessionStorage.token;
                    var decodedToken=jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
                    vm.loggedInUser= decodedToken.Username;
                }
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the angular html code:

```
<div ng-if="vm.isLoggedin()" class="loginContent"
     ng-controller="loginController as vm">

  <form class="Blogform">
      <form class="Blogform">
          <textarea name=text id="text" rows="40" cols="150"
                    placeholder= "Share.."> 
          </textarea>
     `</form>`
      <div class="heading">`hi {{vm.loggedInUser}}!</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `ng-controller` and `ng-if` directives need to be on separate `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `{{ vm.loggedInUser }}` tells AngularJS to look on its `$scope` identifier for the property you referenced, i.e `vm.loggedInUser`.

Thus, all attempts to render data from your controller need that data to be on the `$scope`.

So, inject `$scope` into your controller:

```
function loginController ($http, $location, $window, authfactory, jwtHelper, $scope) {}
```

Then put vm on `$scope`:

```
$scope.vm = this; // not sure why you're assigning a reference to *this*.
```

Now `vm.loggedInUser` will be rendered in your template.

Comment: By adding it at the end to the scope is basically the same as not using the vm controller naming at all, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 issues here. Either its because you're using ng-if before attaching the controller to your div. 
Here:

```
 <div ng-if="vm.isLoggedin()" class="loginContent" ng-controller="loginController as vm">
```

Try:

```
<div class="loginContent" ng-controller="loginController as vm" ng-if="vm.isLoggedin()">
```

Or Use a self invoked function to wrap around your code. This is assuming there aren't any other errors in a factory or service that's bringing the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you have been missing is to cause for using controllers 'as vm'. You can define your controllers as simple functions with this but to make it work you need to return a value - the controller itself. Hence the 'return vm;' at the end fo the following snippet. Hope this helps!

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('loginController', loginController);

function loginController(){
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.loggedInUser = "hello";
  
  return vm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="loginContent" ng-controller="loginController as vm">
    <div class="heading">`hi {{vm.loggedInUser}}!</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```